# Autofac: Custom delegate for single instance object exposed via interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

Consider the below code:

```
public interface IProduct { };

public class ConcreteProduct : IProduct
{
    public ConcreteProduct(int id, DateTime manufacturedDate, DateTime expiryDate)
    {

    }
}

public delegate IProduct ProductFactory(int id, DateTime manufacturedDate, DateTime expiryDate);
```

I need to maintain a single instance for the `IProduct`, which is to be created by someone by calling the `ProductFactory` delegate, which will return a `ConcreteProduct`.

Please suggest how to achieve this with Autofac.

Comment: It's not Autofac's job to create data objects (such as DTOs, Entities and messages) for you. A DI Container's job is to compose object graphs of application components (the classes that hold the application's behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
public delegate IProduct ProductFactory(int id, DateTime manufacturedDate, DateTime expiryDate);

public interface IProduct { };

public class ConcreteProduct : IProduct
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ManufactureDt { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDt { get; set; }
    public ConcreteProduct(int id, DateTime manufacturedDate, DateTime expiryDate)
    {
        ProductId = id;
        ManufactureDt = manufacturedDate;
        ExpiryDt = expiryDate;
    }
}

//Class where Factory is injected
public class ProductOrder
{
    private readonly ProductFactory _prodFactory;
    public ProductOrder(ProductFactory prodFactory)
    {
        _prodFactory = prodFactory;
    }

    public IProduct GenerateOrder()
    {
        return _prodFactory.Invoke(10, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(4));
    }
}
```

Autofac registrations:

```
    static IContainer container;

    private static void InitializeAutoFac()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Register<ProductFactory>(context =>
        {
            return (int id, DateTime dt, DateTime dt2) =>
            {
                IProduct prod = new ConcreteProduct(id, dt, dt2);
                return prod;
            };
        }).SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<ProductOrder>().AsSelf();

        container = builder.Build();
    }
```

Usage:

```
static void Main()
{
    InitializeAutoFac();

    ProductOrder pOrder = container.Resolve<ProductOrder>();
    IProduct prod = pOrder.GenerateOrder();
}
```

Hope it helps.